# emberjs resetting a routes model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I want to reset a model on a route after a user clicks the sort header on a table:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
//import _ from 'lodash';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    needs: 'event-profile',
    model: function(){
        var parentmodel = this.modelFor('eventProfile').get('slug');
        return this.store.find('listingEvent', { eventInstanceSlug: parentmodel, skip: 0, limit: 20 });
  },
  actions: {
        orderByStart: function(){
            this.set('loading', true);
            console.debug('order by start');
            var _this = this;
            var parentmodel = this.modelFor('eventProfile').get('slug');
            this.store.find('listingEvent', { eventInstanceSlug: parentmodel, skip: 0, limit: 20, sort: 'start' })
            .then(function(model){
                _this.set('loading', false);
                _this.set('model', model);
            });
        }
     }
});
```

orderByStart is getting fired and i can see the correct data is being returned but setting the model with `_this.set('model', model);` doesn't seem to have any effect?

What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: You shouldn't reload the model just to switch back the order.  Also, to better answer this, it would help to know how you are sorting the model.

Comment: I'm not sure I get you - how does it matter how my backend is sorting these records?

Comment: Also - if I don't send the sort to the server how do you expect this to work? Sorry - I'm not sure you understand the question?

Comment: You're right, didn't realize from your question that the sort was affecting what data was returned.  The issue is that you are setting model on the route instead of on the controller. `_this.controllerFor('my-route').set('model', model);`

Comment: Ahaaaa - I did get it working but a different way. I'll twat your way when I get into the office. Set it as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue is that your action handler is on your route but the model property you need to change is on your controller.  The fast change is to call controllerFor.

e.g. this: `_this.set('model', model);`

becomes: `_this.controllerFor('my-route').set('model', model);`

However, this could be better done by moving your action handler to the controller itself.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'event-profile',

  loading : false,

  actions: {
    orderByStart: function(){

      this.set('loading', true);
      var _this = this;
      var parentmodel = this.get('controllers.eventProfile.model.slug');

      this.store.find('listingEvent', { eventInstanceSlug: parentmodel, skip: 0, limit: 20, sort: 'start' })
        .then(function(model){
          _this.setProperties({ loading : false, model : model});
        });
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Good work chap - I hate this weirdness between controllers and routes  -I heard controllers are going to go all together - how will this be handled then?!

Comment: Routable components.  When you stop to think about it, you put actions on controllers and almost nothing in views, it makes sense to combine them which is basically all a component really is.